# Networkx visualization

Tags: visualization, networkx

I am new to netwrokx and I have a big network as follows that I need to just visualize its blue nodes:

[image]

Is there any way to see just blue nodes while the distance between them is same as the real graph's?
My desired output would be something like following one:
[image]

Result of using pos layout is as follows:
[image]

Joel helped med to find out the result and I share codes and outcome here for those who have the similar question:

Answer Codes:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, nodelist = blue_nodes, node_color = 
'blue',with_labels=False)
```

outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a network `G`, with a list of "blue" nodes `bluenodes`, we can define a set of positions, and then draw just the blue nodes.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) #there are other layouts that you might want to try.
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = bluenodes, node_color = 'blue', with_labels=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. I added the result of using pos layout to the trend of main question because I couldn't add screenshot to the comment. It gives me a better insight into position of nodes that are important to me. But, because of large number of edges, I still can't find all of the nodes. I even disables labels but it didn't work! I have no idea why nodes have red color!

Comment: I've made 3 changes to correct mistakes I made.  [`draw_networkx_nodes` so it's just the nodes, set `node_color` instead of `color`, and removed labels by using `with_labels=False`].  Try it now.